# Mover elementos en el DOM con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, css3

Estoy tratando de mover elementos a otra parte del DOM con jquery, si se logran mover pero como son elementos que se van a repetir dinamicamente, el contenido que le di appendTo se duplica en cada uno de los elementos. Como puedo evitar que se duplique??

```js
$(".detalles .precio").appendTo($(".contenedor-precio-nivel"));
$(".detalles .nivel").appendTo($(".contenedor-precio-nivel"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="contenido">
  <div class="detalles">
    <div class="precio">$120.00</div>
    <div class="promedio">
      <div class="estrellas">
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
      </div>
      <span>5.0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="calificaciones"><span>(20,000)</span>
      <p>Calificaciones</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nivel">Nivel Avanzado</div>
    <div class="contenedor-precio-nivel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contenido">
  <div class="detalles">
    <div class="precio">$20.00</div>
    <div class="promedio">
      <div class="estrellas">
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
      </div>
      <span>5.0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="calificaciones"><span>(20,000)</span>
      <p>Calificaciones</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nivel">Nivel Principiante</div>
    <div class="contenedor-precio-nivel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por ejemplo, tengo 3 divs padres que contienen a el contenedor del precio y el nivel, entonces al ejecutar ese código de arriba, se duplica 3 veces el precio y 3 veces el nivel, ¿cómo puedo evitar que se duplique?

Comment: Por favor, añade también el HTML para crear un [mcve] en la propia pregunta y que podamos ver mejor el problema. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Ya agregue el html

Comment: He duplicado la parte del HTML para que se vea  el problema. Dime si ahora ya se ve el problema bien

Comment: Si me funciono, muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque cuando mueves los elementos no especificas dentro de qué padre se encuentra el `.contenedor-precio-nivel` de destino. Entonces se copia a todos los que existen, duplicándose el contenido en diferentes partes.

Una posible solución sería usar `.each` para seleccionar los elementos que se van a mover, y entonces puedes usar los selectores de ancestro dentro del `appendTo`. Algo como esto (formateado y comentado para que se vean las diferentes partes):

```
// para cada elemento con clase precio dentro de detalles
$(".detalles .precio").each(function(elemento) {
  // añadirlo al final del elemento...
  $(this).appendTo(
    // buscar el ancestro de precio con clase detalles 
    // y buscar dentro de ese, al que tenga la clase contenedor-precio-nivel
    $(this).closest(".detalles").find(".contenedor-precio-nivel")
  );
});
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$(".detalles .precio").each(function(elemento) {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).closest(".detalles").find(".contenedor-precio-nivel"));
});

$(".detalles .nivel").each(function(elemento) {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).closest(".detalles").find(".contenedor-precio-nivel"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="contenido">
  <div class="detalles">
    <div class="precio">$120.00</div>
    <div class="promedio">
      <div class="estrellas">
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
      </div>
      <span>5.0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="calificaciones"><span>(20,000)</span>
      <p>Calificaciones</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nivel">Nivel Avanzado</div>
    <div class="contenedor-precio-nivel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contenido">
  <div class="detalles">
    <div class="precio">$20.00</div>
    <div class="promedio">
      <div class="estrellas">
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
        <i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
      </div>
      <span>5.0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="calificaciones"><span>(20,000)</span>
      <p>Calificaciones</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nivel">Nivel Principiante</div>
    <div class="contenedor-precio-nivel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si funcionó, muchas gracias